# Explode after Implode

Tags: php

I have this array, and I've tried to return it like the same way before.

Example:

```
        $this->permission_array = array(
                                    'orders'                => 1,
                                    'orders_Status'         => 0,
                                    'schools'               => 0,
                                    'accommodation'         => 0,
                                    'users'                 => 1,
                                    'news'                  => 0,
                                    'blocks'                => 1,
                                    'settings'              => 0,
                                    'videos'                => 1,
                                    );
```

after implode it and insert to to database it became like this.

```
USER_ID     USER_NAME           USER_PERMISSION
---------------------------------------------------
  1302       Othman             1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1
```

and now if I used **explode** it return as an array but the keys are not the same. how I can transfer these values to the same array not like this array:

```
[0] => 1
[1] => 0
[2] => 0
[3] => 0
[4] => 1
[5] => 0
[6] => 1
[7] => 0
[8] => 1
```

Is there anyway to change the last array to the first array again? Thank's in advance.

### ***My Desision is to change the database field and create a new table. Thank you guys***

Comment: Nope.  You stored it without that data, so you can't get it back (unless you know that it's always in that order).  By the way, you might want to look at database normalization.  Storing data in a comma separated list in a database is almost always an antipattern.

Comment: agreed with Corbin. in most cases it is against the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table of user_permissions:

```
permission_id    permission_name
```

Then create a table of users_2_permissions

```
user_id          permission_id
```

When you want to restore the array, you'll do a `JOIN` on users, users_2_permissions and user_permissions.

Answer (score 1):

The `implode` function only cares about the values.

Instead of use `implode` and `explode`, you could use `json_encode` and `json_decode` to use json as your format to save, that will remain your key infomations.

But the real problem is your db design.

Answer (score 0):

Use `serialize()` to store arrays in the database.

Comment: Technically correct, but *PLEASE* do not encourage people to store an array in a relational database.

Comment: @Corbin I just provided an answer to the question

Comment: Yeah, but if someone asked you how to paint a wall with a rake, would you answer them directly or point out the error in their method?  (Though obviously this is a bit different...  My point is just that a direct answer may keep the OP doing this.  And way too many people already store CSV in a DB.)

Answer (score 0):

You can create another table for this, for example USER_PERMISSIONS (id, user_id, orders, orders_Status, ...) where id is a primary key, user_id is a foreign key to USERS table, and all the other fields contain values for respective permissions. This approach can add a bit more complexity to your queries, but it's still better than serializing arrat into string.

Answer (score 0):

simple ...

```
    $a=explode(',',$permitions_from_database);
    $names=array('orders','orders_Status','etc','etc')

    $i=0;
    foreach($names as $name)
    {
    $permission_array[$name]=$a[$i];
    $i++;
    }
```

But i think you should put the data on different columns, its better to query the database for who has permissions for something rather than bringing all the data to php and then process it.

I hope that it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Tho not implied, you need Normalization, store the value as a one whole string in double quotes "" in case it will affect your db eliminating the need to restructure your db.